# Sequence with algebra (Hints preferred over answer)

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a,b,c$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence. Prove that the following are also consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt c},\ \frac1{\sqrt c+\sqrt a},\ \frac1{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$$

I tried using the definition of arithmetic sequence so $b=a+d$ and $c=a+2d$, and then I tried to isolate the 2 variables $b$ and $d$ to express $b$ in terms of $d$ so I can then substitute it into the 2nd term and 1st term, and then subtract the 1st from the 2nd term to get $d$. However, when I tried to isolate the 2 terms, I got:
$$
2d^2=(\sqrt b-\sqrt{b+d})+(\sqrt b-\sqrt{b-d})
$$
Realizing that this question cannot be this complicated as it is only a <10 mark question for IB HL Maths, I think that I am forgetting something important. Could you guys give me a hint rather than answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
$$\frac1{x+y}=\frac{x-y}{x^2-y^2}.$$

Comment: Ohhh, so multiply the expression 1/(a+b) by (a-b)/(a-b)?

Comment: I totally forgot, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{b}}{d}$. Similarly for the other two expressions.  Then show that sum of the first term and last term is twice the middle term.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\ca{\sqrt c+\sqrt a}
\def\bc{\sqrt b+\sqrt c}
\def\ab{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$
Three numbers $x,y,z$ form an arithmetic sequence if and only if $z=y+(y-x)$, i.e. $2y=x+z$. So $2b=a+c$ and we want to show

$$
\frac{2}{\ca}=\frac{1}{\bc}+\frac{1}{\ab}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $(\ca)(\bc)(\ab)$, we have
$$
2(\bc)(\ab)=(\ca)(\ab)+(\ca)(\bc).
$$

> Expanding out, we get the equation$$2(b+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc})=(a+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc})+(c+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{bc}).$$ And this is equivalent with $$2b=a+c.$$

---

Hope this helps